# Call Wordpress Archive page with multiple category IDs

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using custom fields on my template page and I want create a hyperlink to multiple category IDs.

This snippet gets my custom post field and returns category IDs 23 and 19, or whatever series I put in the custom field, ie: 23,9,17:

```
<?php $featuredpost_cat = get_field('featured_category_id'); ?>
```

I want to do something like this (I don't know the proper calls and syntax):

```
<a href="<?php wp link to $featuredpost_cat ?>"My Link Title </a>
```

I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

To category link by category id:

`<?php
  $featuredpost_cat = get_field('featured_category_id');
  $category_link = get_category_link( $featuredpost_cat );
  ?>

  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>"> My Link Title </a>`

You can get more details about this in the wordpress function reference site.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="http://www.yourwebiteurl/yourcategoriepage/<?=$featuredpost_cat?>">My Link Title</a>
```

Im just giving an general solution how you can link to the id hope this helps.